# React Router, pushState with an Express Server

Tags: express, reactjs, webpack, react-router, pushstate

quick question regarding using React-Router. I'm having trouble getting my server to handle pushState (if this is the correct term). Originally, I was using a module called `connect-history-api-fallback`, which was a middleware that enabled me to only server up static files form my `dist` directory. Visiting the client www.example.com obviously worked and I could navigate throughout the site, additionally, refreshing at any route like www.example.com/about - could also work.

However, I recently added one simple API endpoint on my Express server for the React app/client to ping. The problem now is that while I can get the initial page load to work (and thus the `/api/news` call to work, to fetch data from a remote service), I can no longer do a refresh on any other routes. For example, now going to www.example.com/about will result in a failed GET request for /about. How can I remediate this? Really appreciate the help! PS - not sure if it matters, but I'm considering implementing Server Side Rendering later on.

```
import express from 'express';
import historyApiFallback from 'connect-history-api-fallback';
import config from '../config';
import chalk from 'chalk';
import fetch from 'node-fetch';
import path from 'path';

const app = express();

// FIXME: Unsure whether or not this can be used.
// app.use(historyApiFallback({
//   verbose : true
// }));

//// DEVELOPMENT MODE ONLY - USING EXPRESS + HMR ////
/* Enable webpack middleware for hot module reloading */
if (config.get('globals').__DEV__) {
  const webpack       = require('webpack');
  const webpackConfig = require('../build/webpack/development_hot');
  const compiler      = webpack(webpackConfig);

  app.use(require('./middleware/webpack-dev')({
    compiler,
    publicPath : webpackConfig.output.publicPath
  }));

  app.use(require('./middleware/webpack-hmr')({ compiler }));
}

//// PRODUCTION MODE ONLY - EXPRESS SERVER /////
if (config.get('globals').__PROD__) {
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist'));
}

//// API ENDPOINTS FOR ALL ENV ////
app.get('/api/news', function (req, res) {
  fetch('http://app-service:5000/news')
    .then( response => response.json() )
    .then( data => res.send(data) )
    .catch( () => res.sendStatus(404) );
});

// Wildcard route set up to capture other requests (currently getting undexpected token '<' error in console)
app.get('*', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist', 'index.html'));
});

export default app;
```

Answer (score 0):

Express works by implementing a series of middleware that you "plug in" in order via `.use`. The cool thing is your routes are also just middlware — so you can separate them out, have them *before* your history fallback, and then only requests that make it past your routes (e.g., didn't match any routes) will hit the fallback.

Try something like the following:

```js
const app = express();

// ...

var routes = exprss.Router();

routes.get('/api/news', function (req, res) {
  fetch('http://app-service:5000/news')
    .then( response => response.json() )
    .then( data => res.send(data) )
    .catch( () => res.sendStatus(404) );
});

app.use(routes);

app.use(historyApiFallback({
  verbose : true
}));
```